# Как выполнять нажатия на экран android программно?

Tags: android, root

Недавно я наткнулся на приложение, которое записывает твои нажатия на экран, а потом повторяет их столько, сколько захочет пользователь. Приложение требует рут. Так вот, мне стало очень любопытно, как выполнять нажатия на экран программно и как вообще использовать другие функции, которые предоставляет рут? Я начинающий в  разработке, поэтому могут быть еще вопросы тут:)

Comment: Вот тут как запускать shell скрипты из андроид приложения:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932102/execute-shell-command-from-android Вот тут примеры shell комманд: https://xakep.ru/2014/10/24/android-shell-script/ А здесь собственно как эмулировать касания на экран:
http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пишу ответ для закрытия темы, т к ответ дали комментарием.